# Find expected value from given PDF (CDF)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

The probability distribution function (or Cumulative Distributions Function) of a discrete random variable $X$ is given by
$$\begin{equation}
  F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
    0, & \text{for $x<-2.5$}.\\
    0.3, & \text{for $-2.5\le x< 0$}.\\
    0.6, & \text{for $0\le x< 1$}.\\
    1, & \text{for }  x\ge 1\\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$
a) Find the probability mass function for this random variable, i.e $P(X = x_j ) = p (x_j)$

 b) $(<1 ) =$ ?

c) Find the Expected value of $X$. ($()=$?) 
d) Find the variance and standard deviation of X. ( $\operatorname {}()=$? and $\sigma_=$?)

here what I tried: 
a) 
$$\begin{equation}
  p(x) = \begin{cases}
    0, & \text{for $x<-2.5$}.\\
    0.3, & \text{for $-2.5\le x< 0$}.\\
    0.3, & \text{for $0\le x< 1$}.\\
    0.4, & \text{for }  x\ge 1\\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$

b) $P(X<1 )= P(X<1 )=0.3+0.3=0.6$ 
c) I know this : $E(X) = p*f(x_i) +... $ but i dont think it is suitable neither this: $\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx$ 
so to find expected value what method i can use ? and for question a) and b) are correct right ? 
Thank you

Comment: Part (a) isn't right. The pmf for a discrete random variable should be defined by point masses, not over intervals. Once you fix that, it should help you with (c) and (d). Part (b) is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is a discrete random variable. So it assumes discrete integral values only.

Hence your $p(x)$ can be correctly written as:
$$\begin{equation}
  p(x) = \begin{cases}
    0.3, & \text{for $x=-2$}.\\
    0.3, & \text{for $x=-1$}.\\
    0.3, & \text{for $x= 0$}.\\
    0.4, & \text{for $x= 1$}.\\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$

As a result, $E(X)=-0.6-0.3+0.4=-0.5$

And so on, you will get the other results as well.